# Server port still open after force close?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, application-server

I have a server running on a local server.  Every once in a while it will freeze up, and I'll need to use a Ctrl+Z to cancel out of it.  The issue is that the port it uses is still open to it after I force close it, and it can't reclaim that port when I restart the program.  So then I need to restart the entire server.

Is there a way I could force that port closed, so the service could open it when it starts back up, or maybe refresh all the ports?

Thanks,
max

Comment: Did you write this program? This is a program bug, most likely failing to set SO_REUSEPORT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctrl-z is a suspend.

You probably want ctrl-c.

You can also send a signal to the individual PID.  For example, if I wanted to close port 80, I could first query open files with lsof:

```
lsof -i tcp:80
```

httpd   24579   root    3u  IPv6 142712111       TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Then send a kill signal:

```
kill -9   24579
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is only suspend your job, place it in the backgroud, so the port is still open. Just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead.

In your case, find out the process which is listening on this port with:

```
# netstat --protocol=ip -nlp | grep :port
```

and kill the PID. No need to reboot the server.